# Laravel Jensseger Mongodb SUM always giving 0

Tags: mongodb, laravel, eloquent, sum

I am using jensseger mongodb in Laravel. When I use sum in the form:

```
User::where(...)->sum('balance');
```

sum always returns 0. I am able to use `User::where(...)->get(['balance'])->sum('balance');` and it returns the correct result, however, my worry is that due to the get(...) in the second example, the entire column (all balances) will be loaded in memory before sum is calculated, and could become a memory hog.

I have two questions: 1. Will the second example become a memory hog due to get(), and if so, how do i get the first example to work?

Comment: What's the executed query? `\DB::enableQueryLog(); User::where(...)->sum('balance'); dd(\DB::getQueryLog());`

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir  Performed both examples with query logging here: https://pastebin.com/akcfjstm

Comment: I assume you use a package like `laravel-mongodb`?

Comment: Yes, I use jensseger mongodb eloquent implementation: https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

Comment: There's already an issue for this problem: https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/1353

Comment: In the meantime: I don't think `->get(['balance'])->sum('balance')` will cause memory problems unless you have (tens of) thousands of items.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Sadly there are no replies to the issue, but thanks for the help.  I will have to go with the ->get(...) solution for now, but it will leave some potentially nasty technical debt as I would like to build with the assumption that there could be millions of records to sum...

Comment: If performance/memory becomes a problem, you can always insert raw SQL into to a query.

Comment: Once again, thank you :) If this is a problem with the library and not my code, I guess I will just make a note of it, and maybe stress-test it later with some seeded dummy data...

Answer (score 0):

you should change the filed to integer or double type with shell command first

```
db.collection.updateMany({}, [ {$set:{ "total_value_usd" : {$toDouble: 
"$total_value_usd"}}} ], {multi:true})
```